# Problem in the Hermite - Hadamard inequality.

Tags: calculus, integration, convex-analysis

**Hermite - Hadamard inequality**

Let $f$ be a convex function on $[a, b]$. Then
$$f \left( \frac{a+b}{2} \right) \leq \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \leq \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}.$$

Why is $f$ an integrable function. That is, why can we write $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ ?

Comment: A convex function on an open interval is continuous.

Comment: Continuous on an open interval. But we have Theorem that if function on closed interval implies integrable. This make me not sure that on open interval, a function is integrable ?

Comment: $f$ is continuous on $(a, b)$; and this integral can then be defined as $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$, which can be shown to exist.